# Expanded nodes overlapping on the existing nodes in d3 v4 force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, simulation, directed-graph, expandable

I'm working on a simple expandable force directed graph.

It seems to work for the most part except that new nodes are being drawn on the existing nodes.

On the node double click event, I'm trying to add new nodes and redrawing the entire graph. The new nodes are being drawn on the existing nodes. Is there are way, I can draw new nodes as separate branch with link to previous set of nodes?

Can someone help to fix this, please!

```
var svg = null,
    links = null,
    nodes = null,
    lables = null,
    labels = null,
    g = null,
    simulation = null,
    zoom = null,
    root = null,
    color = null,
    width = 0,
    height = 0,
    graph = { nodes: [], links: [] };

var colors = ["#b4a0ff", "#409AE1", "#EF6950", "#40C5AF", "#A07A19", "#AC30C0", "#EB9A72", "#BA86F5", "#EA22A8"];

myPluginLoadEvent(function () {
    onload();
});

function myPluginLoadEvent(func) {
    // assign any pre-defined functions on 'window.onload' to a variable
    var oldOnLoad = window.onload;
    // if there is not any function hooked to it
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        // you can hook your function with it
        window.onload = func
    } else { // someone already hooked a function
        window.onload = function () {
            // call the function hooked already
            oldOnLoad();
            // call your awesome function
            func();
        }
    }
}

function circleColour(d) {

    if (d.group == "0") {
        return "#CA5010";
    } else if (d.group == "1") {
        return "#038387";
    } else if (d.group == "2") {
        return "#B54085";
    } else if (d.group == "3") {
        return "rgba(198, 45, 205, 0.8)";
    } else {
        return "rgba(198, 45, 205, 0.8)";
    }
}

function linkColour(d) {
    if (d.direction == "incoming") {
        return "#4052AB";
    } else if (d.direction == "outgoing") {
        return "#40C5AF";
    }

    return "#FFC83D";
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    }
    d3.select(this).raise().attr("stroke", "black");
}

function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
        .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
        .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    }
    d3.select(this).attr("stroke", null);
}

function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function ticked() {
    links
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    labels
        .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x })
        .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y })

    nodes
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
}

function onDoubleClick(d) {
    if (d.id == "S" || d.expanded) {
        return;
    }

    d.expanded = true;
    expandNode(d.id);
    redenderGraph();
}

function onSelect(d) { }

function initializeDisplay() {
    var graphDiv = document.getElementById("graph");
    width = graphDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    height = graphDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    console.log("SVG width:" + width);
    console.log("SVG height:" + height);

    zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.3, 8])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg = d3.select(graphDiv).append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('style', "border:1px solid black")
        .call(zoom);

    svg.append("defs").append("marker")
        .attr("id", "arrowhead")
        .attr("viewBox", "-0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 20)
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 9)
        .attr("markerHeight", 5)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .attr("xoverflow", "visible")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
        .attr('fill', '#999')
        .style('stroke', 'none');

    g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "everything")
        .attr("fill", "#A07A19")
        .attr("cursor", "pointer")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 8 + "," + height / 8 + ")");

    links = g.append("g")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .selectAll(".link");

    labels = g.append("g")
        .selectAll(".text");

    nodes = g.append("g")
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .selectAll(".node");

    simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(60))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
        .force("attraceForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300));
}

function redenderGraph() {

    nodes = nodes.data(graph.nodes);
    nodes.exit().remove();
    var newNodes = nodes.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill", circleColour)
        .on('click', onSelect)
        .on('dblclick', onDoubleClick)
        .call(zoom)
        .merge(nodes);

    newNodes.append("title").text(d => d.id);
    nodes = nodes.merge(newNodes);

    labels = labels.data(graph.nodes)
    labels.exit().remove();
    labels = labels.enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .text(d => d.id)
        .attr('dx', 6)
        .attr('dy', 3)
        .attr("fill", "#BF7034")
        .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
        .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
        .merge(labels);

    links = links.data(graph.links);
    links.exit().remove();
    links = links.enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
        .style("stroke", linkColour)
        .merge(links);

    updateForces();
}

function updateForces() {

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

    simulation.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(60))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter())
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(d => d.r * 6));

    simulation.alpha(0.5).restart();
}

function expandNode(id, ng) {
    var names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

    names.forEach(n => {
        console.log("Adding node. id:" + id + n);
        graph.nodes.push({ "id": id + n, "group": id.length });

        console.log("Adding link, source:" + id + " target:" + id + n);
        graph.links.push({ "source": id, "target": id + n });
    });
}

function onload() {

    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
        var graphDiv = document.getElementById("graph");
        var w = graphDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var h = graphDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
    });

    graph.nodes.push({ "id": 'S', "group": 0, "expanded": false });
    expandNode("S");
    initializeDisplay();
    redenderGraph();
}
```